# Why postgres is slow updating a simple JSONB field?

Tags: postgresql

I am running on postgresql 12 and I have a pretty small table `users` (~5000 records).

I am logging slow queries and I found that updating JSONB fields is pretty slow, here is an example:

```
update "users" set "artifacts" = '[{"xx": "xxx", "xxx": "xxx"}]' where "id" = 1000;
```

It is a pretty simple query on an index, but in my production node this query pops out in the slow
queries. (~100ms).

I run an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on it but can't get nothing useful, at least for my knowledge :)

https://explain.depesz.com/s/2DGg

If I run an UPDATE query on the same table, but on a non-JSONB field the query is super fast.

Any hint?

Comment: The execution time is **3** milliseconds on the server, not 100ms. So any difference you see is caused by your application or network latency

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this query has been run on staging environment, in the slow query log it shows an average of 83ms

Comment: Then please show us the **slow** query plan.

Comment: jsonb does have some overhead when inserting (or updating) the data: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-json.html

Answer (score 0):

The slow query log only shows you the times it was slow.  How many times did it run when it wasn't slow?  You can use pg_stat_statements to help find that out.  (You could also log the duration of every query to avoid selection bias, but that might cause excessive log bloat).

> If I run an UPDATE query on the same table, but on a non-JSONB field the query is super fast.

And when you ran this query on stage, it was also super fast.  Maybe it is only slow when your server is severely overloaded.  Is the column indexed?  Maybe it had to stop to clean up the fastupdate buffer.